# RealmのJavaからkotlinへ書き換えたい

Tags: java, realm, kotlin

以下の処理をkotlinで書きたいのですが
ご教授のほどよろしくお願いします。
公式のDocumentを探したのですが見つけられなかったため質問させてください。
やりたいことはrealmの読み書きが発生したときの通知を実装したいです

```
private Realm realm;
private RealmChangeListener realmListener;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
      realmListener = new RealmChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChange(Realm realm) {
        }};
      realm.addChangeListener(realmListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // Remove the listener.
        realm.removeChangeListener(realmListener);
        // Close the Realm instance.
        realm.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kotlin pluginを入れたAndroid Studioであれば、`Code` メニューに `Convert Java File to Kotlin File`というのがあるのでこれを使うと自動的にKotlinのコードに変換してくれます。

例えば質問にあるコードを変換すると以下のようになります。Kotlinとしてはベストなコードではないですが、これをスタート地点として、`lazy`を使って`var`を`val`に変えていったり　`!!`を排除する方向で修正していくのがいいのではないかと思います。

```
class MyActivity : Activity() {
    private var realm: Realm? = null
    private var realmListener: RealmChangeListener<Realm>? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
        realmListener = RealmChangeListener<Realm> { }
        realm!!.addChangeListener(realmListener)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        // Remove the listener.
        realm!!.removeChangeListener(realmListener)
        // Close the Realm instance.
        realm!!.close()
    }
}
```

Comment: コード変換は[オンライン](https://try.kotlinlang.org/)でも試すことが出来ます。（右上のConvert from Java）現時点では回答にあるものとは異なるコードを出力するようです。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！
こちらKotlinの変換がうまく働かず、できたりできなかったりします。助かりました。